# c# Task не запускается из библиотеки

Tags: c#, асинхронность, task, async-await

В библиотеки dll есть класс с асинхронным методом.

```
public class FlowCheck
{
  public static void Run()
  {
    // Код
  }
  public static async void RunAsync()
  {
    await Task.Run(() => FlowCheck.Run());
  }
}
```

В программе пытаюсь запустить его, но программа сразу завершает свою работу.

```
public class Program
{
  FlowCheck.RunAsync();
}
```

При этом если, я переносу класс из dll в программу, все работает отлично. Я только начал работать с Task, подскажите что я делаю не так, на Гугл нашел подобное, но там либо синхронное выполнение, либо не получается разобраться. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Чтобы дождаться окончания асинхронного метода - вам нужен оператор await. Да-да, в Main он тоже нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async void` невозможно ожидать, не используйте `async void`, это плохая практика.

```
public class FlowCheck
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        // Код
    }
    public static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Run());
    }
}
```

```
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await FlowCheck.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Или даже так

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = FlowCheck.RunAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Запущено.");
    await task;
    Console.WriteLine("Закончилось.");
}
```

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Выдает ошибку: Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<int>'.

Comment: @Дмитрий вы невнимательно скопировали код. Перепроверьте всё ещё раз. У меня `async` на месте.

Comment: Да вы полностью правы, я не посмотрел на метод Main. Большое вам спасибо.